# how to pass data from multiple checkboxes created in django template using for loop to views.py without using forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

This is my html form in which i have a text field for a word and i am running a for loop which created checkbox for the list of document a user has and displays it as form.

```
<body>
<form id="form" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset id="User">
    <legend>Your details:</legend>
        <p><label for="word">Enter your word</label>
            <input type="text" id="word" name="word">
        </p>
        {% for doc in docs %}
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ doc.document_id }}" name="docid" value="{{ doc.path }}">
            <label for="{{ doc.document_id }}"> {{ doc.document_name }} </label><br>
        </p>
        {% endfor%}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

In `views.py` I have below method which loads this html page

```
def client_home(request):
    client_pr = Client_Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
    events = Event.objects.filter(client_id=client_pr.pk)
    name = request.POST.get('word')
    id = request.POST.get('docid')
    print(name)
    print(id)
    docs = []
    for eve in events:
        docs = Document.objects.filter(event_id=eve)
    context = {'events': events, 'docs': docs}
    return render(request, 'Elasticsearch/form.html', context)
```

My question is as i am using a for loop create checkbox field based on number of documents a user has and when I try to print them in my `Views.py` file it is only priniting last document id whose checkbox is created and not all the documents.

Comment: I think you can use jquery to push data in your checkboxes :)

Answer (score 0):

From seeing your view, I assume you want to pass a list of documents specific to a user to your template. Currently you are overwriting `docs` in every iteration of your for loop.

Change

```
docs = Document.objects.filter(event_id=eve)
```

to

```
docs += Document.objects.filter(event_id=eve)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to get all the selected values from your checkbox, so:

```
id_list = request.POST.getlist('docid')
```

Otherwise using `get` will only return the last one.